# How can I install OpenBSD using the serial console, without external monitor? With a bootable USB stick?

Tags: usb, openbsd, serial-console

How can I install OpenBSD on my HP Server using the serial console,
without external monitor?

I have no monitor in the Datacenter, but
I have my Laptop with Debian/GNU/Linux. So far so good.

How do you make under OpenBSD a bootable USB stick?

To install OpenBSD
over the serial console without the need of an external monitor?

Comment: Or, with a suitable network (DHCP, TFTP, and etc), see `autoinstall(8)`

Answer (score 2):

> Create a USB flash drive with which they install OpenBSD directly
>   from the serial console. Without external monitor. Direct with the
>   Laptop! Port com0 speed 115200
>
> **1) Download image from:**
>    https://openbsd.delfic.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/amd64/install60.fs
>
> **2) Enter on the OpenBSD host:**
>
> pwd
>
> /home/tom
>
> Then
>
> vnconfig -c vnd0 /home/tom/install60.fs
>
> **3) mount /dev/vnd0a /mnt**
>
> ls -l /mnt/etc/
>      boot.conf
>
> **If no output, then**
>
> mkdir /mnt/etc/
>
> **Then/otherwise**
>
> echo "stty com0 115200" > /mnt/etc/boot.conf
>
> echo "set tty com0" >> /mnt/etc/boot.conf
>
> umount /dev/vnd0a
>
> vnconfig -u vnd0
>
> **USB stick into the usb port**
>
> dmesg | grep sd0
>
> sd0 at scsibus4 targ 1 lun0:
>
> USB stick produce:
>
> dd if=/home/tom/install60.fs of=/dev/rsd0c bs=1m
>
> **That's it:**
>
> reboot the (HP) Server and install OpenBSD with USB Stick
>      directly over the serial console without the need
>      of an external monitor with your Linux Laptop!
>      Chance the BIOS boot order to USB. Plugin the USB to the HP Server
>      an then reboot the HP Server and install OpenBSD 6.0 current
>      with your Linux Box on the serial console.
>
> Open a console on the Linux or BSD Box and type
>
> minicom -b 115200
>
> Now you can install OpenBSD via serial console.
>
> Vim

Comment: You first posted this answer as a its own "question". Now you post it again as the answer to your own question. What gives?

Comment: Sorry but, this post is the right one